# Apache NiFi: read json file in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, apache-nifi, ecma

I am new to NiFi. My question is how can we read json file in ECMAScript while using excute script process. I want to load json file with mapping json for schema mapping.

Comment: By "load json file", do you mean JSON in the FlowFile content, or an external file?

Comment: @James - i want to load external file

Answer (score 2):

I have an post on my blog about how to read in a flow file containing JSON using ExecuteScript with ECMAScript:

http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/03/executescript-json-to-json-revisited.html

There is also another StackOverflow question similar to your use case of reading in a mapping file and applying it to incoming data (using Groovy):

[Apache NiFi ExecuteScript: Groovy script to replace Json values via a mapping file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577453/apache-nifi-executescript-groovy-script-to-replace-json-values-via-a-mapping-fi)

Not sure if this helps too but I have another post on validating JSON with ExecuteScript (but Groovy not ECMAScript) using JSONSchema: http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/05/validating-json-in-nifi-with.html